# Sybase SQL - Regular expression escaping metacharacters

Tags: sql, regex, sybase-asa

I'm using Sybase SQL (ASA) and currenty I'm working with regular expressions.

My task is to check strings if they only contains numbers, '+','-' or '/'
like following string: '+49176/3421094'

My statement looks something like that (just a test):

```
Select * from (select '+49176/3421094' Tele from dummy) a
where Tele SIMILAR TO '[0-9/-\+]*'
```

In the documentation it says that metacharacters have to be escaped with '\' but if I execute this statement an sql error is thrown with the message "unknown metacharacter".

My question is: How do I have to escape metacharacters (espacially in classes []) ?

Comment: Generally, you don't have to escape things within classes.  (And you may want to put the `-` last in the class, so as not to make a range between `/` and `+`.)

Comment: It doesn't work neither:
  
Invalid regular expression: unexpected metacharacter in '[0-9/+-]*'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using "REGEXP" instead of "SIMILAR TO":

```
Select * from (select '+49176/3421094' Tele from dummy) a
where Tele REGEXP '[0-9/-\+]*'
```